# SQL See Whether Two or More Columns In a Table is Greater Than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have ran in to a little problem and would appreciate any help.

My Table is such:

```
CASH | CREDIT CARD | DEBIT CARD | ACCOUNT | OTHER
-------------------------------------------------
0.00   0.00          0.00         0.00      0.00

1.00   0.00          0.00         0.00      0.00

2.00   1.00          0.00         0.00      0.00
```

My aim is to `SELECT * FROM` any of the above rows that have more than one column > 0.

So the third row would be selected in this scenario with the above table.

Comment: So what are you asking? And what have you tried?

Comment: Can any values be less than 0?

Comment: 4 choose 2 combinations.

Comment: If you are trying to return rows that have at least two non-zero columns, you could accomplish this with a `WHERE` clause but it may be somewhat lengthy to accomodate all variations of the column values.

Comment: @jarlh you mean greater?

Comment: No, I asked if there can be any negative values, or is 0 the smallest possible values?

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT 
  [CASH], [CREDIT CARD], [DEBIT CARD], [ACCOUNT], [OTHER]
FROM table
WHERE
  CASE WHEN [CASH] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
  CASE WHEN [CREDIT CARD] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
  CASE WHEN [DEBIT CARD] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
  CASE WHEN [ACCOUNT] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
  CASE WHEN [OTHER] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END >= 2
```

Comment: Loving this solution, concise and elegant +1

Comment: when using sql server 2012 or above this is shorter than case when...:    IIF([CASH]>0,1,0) + IIF([CREDIT CARD]>0,1,0) ....

Comment: yes must be the same, as SQL Server internally converts IIF to CASE WHEN :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [t-clausen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30374853/15498) but just as an exercise, I decide to try it as an [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) followed by a `PIVOT`, so that we could write it using more of the general SQL tools:

```
declare @t table (SomeID int,Cash money,Credit money,Debit money,Account money,Other money)
insert into @t(SomeID,Cash,Credit,Debit,Account,Other) values
(1,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00),
(2,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00),
(3,2.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00)

;With Unpiv as (
    select *,SUM(CASE WHEN MoneyValue > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY SomeID) as cnt
    from @t t
        unpivot (MoneyValue for MoneyType in (Cash,Credit,Debit,Account,Other)) x
), Repiv as (
    select *
    from Unpiv u
        pivot (SUM(MoneyValue) for MoneyType in (Cash,Credit,Debit,Account,Other)) x
    where
        cnt >= 2
)
select * from Repiv
```

This does assume that you've got another column (here, called `SomeID`) by which each row can be uniquely identified.

Result:

```
SomeID      cnt         Cash                  Credit                Debit                 Account               Other
----------- ----------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
3           2           2.00                  1.00                  0.00                  0.00                  0.00
```

Just hoping the above might be more adaptable for some variants of the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  [CASH], [CREDIT CARD], [DEBIT CARD], [ACCOUNT], [OTHER]
FROM table
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (VALUES ([CASH]),([CREDIT CARD]),([DEBIT CARD]),([ACCOUNT]),([OTHER])) t(value)
  WHERE value > 0
) >= 2
```